# Handling null in Freemarker

Tags: java, null, freemarker

**Situation:**

- Old java project using freemarker has many finished templates working great.
- Every template is using data form Transaction object.
- This transaction object is very large, because wraps all data about transaction.
- In templates is a lot of expression like this:
  get("object1").getNestedObject2().getNestedObject3().getValue();

**Problem:**
New requirements appear: All templates have to be process for preview with no real data. All numbers should be Zero and all string should be ---.

**Unsatisfactory solutions:**

1. Remake all  templates to check null values. (Lot of work and not safe)
2. Create Transaction object that contains all default value. (Lot of work)

Well my question is: Can I say to Freemarker, that if he finds null or finds null along the way, that he should use 0 instead if he was expecting number or --- if he was expecting String.

Or do you see any better solution?

Comment: Which versions of Freemarker and Java are you using? Also, are you using any other framework that help you tie these technologies?

Comment: I am using freeMarker 2.3.20 and java 1.7. No I do not use any other framework.

Comment: Can you transform your transaction object into a flat map to simplify everything ?

Comment: I do not see any easy way how to do it. It seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show a dummy data model to the templates, your best bet is probably a custom `ObjectWrapper` (see `Configuration.setObjectWrapper`). Everything that reads the data model runs through the `TemplateModel`-s, and the root `TemplateModel` is made by the `ObjectWrapper`, thus it can control what values the templates get for what names. But the question is, when you have to return a dummy value for a name, how can you tell what its type will be? It's not just about finding out if it will be a string or a number, but also if it will be a method (like `getNestedObject2`) or a hash (something that can be followed by `.`). What can help there is that FreeMarker allows a value to have multiple types, so you can return a value that can be used as a method and as a hash and as a string, for example. Depending on the application that hack is might be good enough, except, you still have to decide if the value is a string or a number, because `${}` will print the numerical value if the value both a string and a number.